# How do i reduce the the difference between space of two ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have make two ul in which

1. having the logo at center
2. having all the required nav_links
   but rendering the navlinks show some gap.
   [image: between them]

I want to no gap between these list.

https://codepen.io/mohit-04/pen/ExQGWqV

`.html`

```
<div>
      <center>
        <ul class="top-header">
          <li>
            Hi
            
          </li>
        </ul>
      </center>
      <ul class="second-header">
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about"> About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/boys">Boys</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/Girls">Girls</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <br />

      <br />
    </div>
```

`.css`

```
li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10%;
}

.top-header{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    /* height: 40%; */
}

.second-header{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: This looks like the default margin of the `<ul>`. You can use your browsers dev tools to inspect the layout of your page in cases like this.

Comment: i am referencing about the space between the two list not the margin between top and first one.

Comment: Yes! Margin! Get comfortable with the dev tools. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/  https://firefox-dev.tools/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you want to obtain this result you just need to set the margin of the ul to 0;

```
ul { margin: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want your list looks like this?[image]

If yes just remove the padding you have given for li.

Comment: yes i got this i have already provided padding for gap . But thanks for help

Comment: But it was too much IG.

Comment: Ok i'll reduce it from now onwards